# jquery droppable - nested divs, get actual target id

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-droppable

I have something like this:

```
    $('#mover' ).draggable({});
    $('div').droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        console.log(event.target.id)
    }
```

then

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="target_1"></div>
    <div id="target_2"></div>
    <div id="target_3"></div>
</div>
```

When I drop mover on a div "container" is returned. how do I return instead the lowest child that the item was dropped on?

Comment: Can you set up a live (minimal/[SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)) [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/), so we can see what you're doing?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make the children of container the drop targets?

```
$('#container').children().droppable(...
```

Comment: then item is duplicating both in parent as well as child though i m using greedy:true

Comment: Any idea how do i stop duplicating the droppable itemes?

Comment: As Dave Thomas mentioned, if you could set up a jsFiddle demo so we can see the code in action that might help determine what is going wrong.

Comment: David and Thomas thanks for your reply. Its a huge app, so can't set up demo on JS fiddle. The scenario is i drag n drop window from left panel window stack to right content panel. After 4 windows the subsequent window will be moved to sandbox(another container) which holds exceeded windows from right content panel. User sometimes want to swap windows from sandbox to right content panel, so he drag n drop on a particular window on right content panel window, where he drag n drop that exact window should be swapped.

Comment: This is the HTML code 
 <div id="content_panel"></div><!--content_panel-->
   <div class="clr"></div>
  </div><!--container-->

Comment: Have a look at this link, necessary code is available here
http://jsfiddle.net/aqDHr/

Comment: Wow, that's a pretty big page of code. I didn't notice anything off hand. What really helps the most is if you can take the time to condense the code on jsFiddle into the smallest working example possible. Try to reproduce the issue with the smallest section of code you can. Often that alone will show you the problem area. It's pretty hard to debug the large codebase you have there now without it being operational.